# Mulitple routes in apache camel - best practice

Tags: apache-camel

i have implemented an apache camel scheduler which performs a task at fixed interval of time . the number of task to be performed have grown now and i am in a confusion to continue with same approach or create multiple route builders .

The approach now , call the DB get all the configured rest details and iterate in the confuguire method of the routerbuilder and build the routes.

code sample :

```
public void configure() {
    for(int i=0; i< list.length;i++){
        from("quartz://myTimer?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=-1")
            .setBody().simple("Current time is ${header.firedTime}")
            .to("stream:out");  
    }
}
```

Here i have only one routebuilder class , configure method has the for loop which creates the multiple routes.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be an approach that won't scale well. If you have 10, or 100 ´list´ items - then, great.

If you have 1000 or 10,000 or 1,000,000 routes defined in the RouteBuilder - will that work? I don't know.

A camel route is meant to model the data flow, not represent the data itself. The data should flow through the routes.

I would remodel your solution and make an in-memory queue via the `seda:` endpoint, and put x items of data (can easily be a `java.lang.Integer`) on to `seda:myqueue`.

Then have a second route which consumes asyncronously from `seda:myqueue`, and processes the data, with whichever timings you choose.

Comment: I have 30 earlier , which is increased to 75 now. So I can go with this approach till 500 ? . Max I can get the processing  request form business is 500 only

Comment: As I said, routes are not meant to represent data, you can try 500 (it might work) but I feel there are other, better ways to model the problem, for example an asynchronous queue (`seda:`).